# What are the triangular prism numbers? Or octahedron numbers?

Tags: geometry

What kinds of solids can be constructed such that if some number of orbs were placed inside said solid, there would be no 'slide filling spaces'? Convex regular polyhedra whose faces are either equilateral triangles or squares* and whose vertices have three or four polygons attached to them. A.K.A, the solids you can construct with just 2*2 Legos. The bigger question is, for some solid, such as an octahedron, what are the number of marbles, or Legos, or anything else, that fit inside as the solid gets bigger?

*Thus meaning all side lengths are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The octahedral numbers would be the sum of two successive [square pyramidal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number).
$$P_n=\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$ is the sum of squares from $1$ to $n^2$.  If you make a pyramid with the base of side $n$ and put another with base of side $n-1$ next to it you get an octahedron, so $$O_n=\frac {n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+\frac {(n-1)n(2n-1)}6=\frac{4n^3+2n}6$$
For a triangular prism, you just stack as many triangles of a given size as you want.

Comment: This is helpful, but I am asking about general solids. Any specific convex regular polyhedron numbers formula can be computed in a few minutes. Also, I was asking about a specific triangular prism and the formula is (n^2+n^3)/2.

Comment: You can't have a formula until you specify the solid.  The formula for your prism assumes that the height matches the base, but it is correct then.